# MTR - How to randomize packetsize?

Tags: networking, network-programming, traceroute

In reviewing the options on MTR in the manual page of MTR, there is an option for packetsize.
Quote:
-s PACKETSIZE, --psize PACKETSIZE
This option sets the packet size used for probing.  It is in bytes, inclusive IP and ICMP headers.
If set to a negative number, every iteration will use a different, random packet size up to that number.

I have attempted different combinations to randomize the packetsize using negative numbers but I do not seem to get this right. I always get errors of invalid syntax.

I have tried these mtr combinations:

```
mtr -b -c 5 -u4 --port 80 --psize -111 meet.google.com
mtr -b -c 5 -u4 --psize negative10 meet.google.com
mtr -b -c 5 -u4 --psize=_-10_ meet.google.com
mtr -b -c 5 -u4 --psize=-10 meet.google.com
mtr -b -c 5 -u4 --psize ((-10)) meet.google.com
mtr -b -c 5 -u4 --psize (-10) meet.google.com
```

The results were:
-bash: syntax error
or
mtr: invalid argument

May anyone please advise what I am doing wrong? Does this option even work?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me either. However once `mtr` is running you can use the `s` key to set the packet size and this allows you to set a negative number, however I can't tell what size packets it is sending in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on version of mtr or its fork, so far it's possible only in older versions
https://github.com/traviscross/mtr/issues/475

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34472893)

Comment: @user16217248 there's a minor slip-up in code in part of comparison for signed/unsigned integers in new mtr versions, something like conversion of signed integer into unsigned one. Details are in the mentioned link.